# scala - restricted way of converting string to number

Tags: java, scala, number-formatting

I have a string variable that needs to be parsed to a double

**Code**:

```
val myString = "9d"
myString.toDouble // produces "9.0" which i don't want. this should throws an error
```

How do I make my string to be interpreted literally so that it produces an exception?

Comment: Interesting question! This applies to pure Java too. One solution: `BigDecimal(myString).toDouble`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, apparently, Java's `java.lang.Double#parseDouble` is able to parse all kinds of strings, e.g. `NaN`, `Infinity` and other.

The answer to your problem seems to be **`BigDecimal(myString).toDouble`**

Out of curiosity, here is, what three different approaches return for various kinds of input strings:

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val strings = Seq("Infinity", "NaN", "9.0d", "9d", "9f", "9.0", "9.1", "1.4e14")
    val parsers = Seq(
      ("Double", (s: String) => s.toDouble),
      ("BigDecimal", (s: String) => BigDecimal(s).toDouble),
      ("NumberFormat", (s: String) => NumberFormat.getNumberInstance.parse(s).doubleValue()),
    )

    for (string <- strings) {
      println(s"\n------------- $string ------------")
      for ((name, parser) <- parsers) {
        val result = Try(parser(string)) match {
          case scala.util.Success(value) => value
          case scala.util.Failure(ex) => ex.toString
        }
        println(name.reverse.padTo(20, " ").reverse.mkString + " -> " + result)
      }

    }
  }
```

Result:

```
------------- Infinity ------------
              Double -> Infinity
          BigDecimal -> java.lang.NumberFormatException
        NumberFormat -> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "Infinity"

------------- NaN ------------
              Double -> NaN
          BigDecimal -> java.lang.NumberFormatException
        NumberFormat -> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "NaN"

------------- 9.0d ------------
              Double -> 9.0
          BigDecimal -> java.lang.NumberFormatException
        NumberFormat -> 9.0

------------- 9d ------------
              Double -> 9.0
          BigDecimal -> java.lang.NumberFormatException
        NumberFormat -> 9.0

------------- 9f ------------
              Double -> 9.0
          BigDecimal -> java.lang.NumberFormatException
        NumberFormat -> 9.0

------------- 9.0 ------------
              Double -> 9.0
          BigDecimal -> 9.0
        NumberFormat -> 9.0

------------- 9.1 ------------
              Double -> 9.1
          BigDecimal -> 9.1
        NumberFormat -> 9.1

------------- 1.4e14 ------------
              Double -> 1.4E14
          BigDecimal -> 1.4E14
        NumberFormat -> 1.4
```

Comment: The second one doesn't work as desired: `val n = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance.parse("9d")` results in `n: Number = 9`

Comment: For the second one to work, you'd need something like: `val s = "9d"; val pos = new ParsePosition(0);
val n = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance.parse(s, pos);
if (pos.getIndex != s.length) throw new NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with `scalaz`:

```
import scalaz.Scalaz._

println("34b".parseDouble) // Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "34b")

println("34.4".parseDouble) // Success(34.4)
```

Comment: No, that still doesn't work: `"9d".parseDouble` -> `Success(9.0)`